# Get the id of a shortcode wp plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

i am trying to make a very simple plugin with a shortcode and i want to get the id of this shortcode.

My simple code is:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: DEMO
Plugin URI: http://www.mydemo.com
Description: DEMO
Version: 0.1 BETA
Author: Paul McKnight
Author URI: http://www.mydemo.com
*/

function demol_handler() {  
  $demolph_output = demoplug_function();  
  return $demolph_output;
}

function demoplug_function() { 
  $demolp_output = "Hello Your Shortcode id is:";  Here i want to display my shortcodes Id
  return $demolp_output;
}

add_shortcode("my_plugin", "demo_handler");

?>
```

The shortcode for this simple plugin is `[my_plugin][/my_plugin]`
So i want to get this id `[my_plugin id=9876][/my_plugin]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to pass the ID from your shortcode handler to the function.

```
function demo_handler( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'my_plugin' ) );

    $demolph_output = demoplug_function( $id );  
    return $demolph_output;
}
add_shortcode( "my_plugin", "demo_handler" );

function demoplug_function( $id ) { 
    $demolp_output = "Hello Your Shortcode id is: " . $id;
    return $demolp_output;
}
```

Usage:

```
[my_plugin id="1"]
```